# WebViewJavascriptBridge - callHandler not working

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I checked the examples but I can't make them run so I made my own project with very simple code but I don't get this library works.

When i press the button "Call handler" nothing happens. What I'm doing wrong?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="nombre"/>
<input type="button" value="Aceptar" onClick="mostrarNombre()"/>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Say hello iOS" />
<br>
<div id='buttons'></div> <div id='log'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mostrarNombre() {
        var txt_nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
        Android.showToast(txt_nombre.value);
    }

    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
    function setupWebViewJavascriptBridge(callback) {
        if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge) { return callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge); }
        if (window.WVJBCallbacks) { return window.WVJBCallbacks.push(callback); }
        window.WVJBCallbacks = [callback];
        var WVJBIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        WVJBIframe.style.display = 'none';
        WVJBIframe.src = 'https://__bridge_loaded__';
        document.documentElement.appendChild(WVJBIframe);
        setTimeout(function() { document.documentElement.removeChild(WVJBIframe) }, 0)
    }

    setupWebViewJavascriptBridge(function(bridge) {
        var uniqueId = 1
        function log(message, data) {
            var log = document.getElementById('log')
            var el = document.createElement('div')
            el.className = 'logLine'
            el.innerHTML = uniqueId++ + '. ' + message + ':<br/>' + JSON.stringify(data)
            if (log.children.length) { log.insertBefore(el, log.children[0]) }
            else { log.appendChild(el) }
        }

        bridge.registerHandler('testJavascriptHandler', function(data, responseCallback) {
            log('ObjC called testJavascriptHandler with', data)
            var responseData = { 'Javascript Says':'Right back atcha!' }
            log('JS responding with', responseData)
            responseCallback(responseData)
        })

        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))

        var callbackButton = document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(document.createElement('button'))
        callbackButton.innerHTML = 'Fire testObjcCallback'
        callbackButton.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            log('JS calling handler "testObjcCallback"')
            bridge.callHandler('testObjcCallback', {'foo': 'bar'}, function(response) {
                log('JS got response', response)
            })
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller class

```
@interface WebViewController () {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *_webView;
}

@property WebViewJavascriptBridge* bridge;

@end

@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize url = _url;


BOOL _Authenticated;
NSURLRequest *_FailedRequest;

#pragma UIWebViewDelegate para usar certificados no validos o expirados

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    BOOL result = _Authenticated;
    if (!_Authenticated) {
        _FailedRequest = request;
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [urlConnection start];
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma NSURLConnectionDelegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_url];
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host]) {
            NSLog(@"trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)pResponse {
    _Authenticated = YES;
    [connection cancel];
    [_webView loadRequest:_FailedRequest];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _url = @"http://MYIP/test/";
    _webView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (_bridge) { return; }

    [WebViewJavascriptBridge enableLogging];

    _bridge = [WebViewJavascriptBridge bridgeForWebView:_webView];
    [_bridge setWebViewDelegate:self];

    [_bridge registerHandler:@"testObjcCallback" handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {
        NSLog(@"testObjcCallback called: %@", data);
        responseCallback(@"Response from testObjcCallback");
    }];

    [self renderButtons:_webView];
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_url]]];


}

- (void)renderButtons:(UIWebView*)webView {
    UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0];

    UIButton *callbackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [callbackButton setTitle:@"Call handler" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [callbackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view insertSubview:callbackButton aboveSubview:webView];
    callbackButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 400, 100, 35);
    callbackButton.titleLabel.font = font;

    UIButton* reloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [reloadButton setTitle:@"Reload webview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reloadButton addTarget:webView action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view insertSubview:reloadButton aboveSubview:webView];
    reloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 400, 100, 35);
    reloadButton.titleLabel.font = font;

    UIButton* safetyTimeoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [safetyTimeoutButton setTitle:@"Disable safety timeout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [safetyTimeoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(disableSafetyTimeout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view insertSubview:safetyTimeoutButton aboveSubview:webView];
    safetyTimeoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(190, 400, 120, 35);
    safetyTimeoutButton.titleLabel.font = font;
}

- (void)callHandler:(id)sender {
    id data = @{ @"greetingFromObjC": @"Hi there, JS!" };
    [_bridge callHandler:@"testJavascriptHandler" data:data responseCallback:^(id response) {
        NSLog(@"testJavascriptHandler responded: %@", response);
    }];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
}


@end
```